# Trying to send an image to Oracle database, but does not open well

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-formats

So, i am trying to send an image to Oracle Database, and it works, but it is not in a good format, beacuse it looks like:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

//image format
```

and I only need the image format, without the top of it.

This is my code for POSTing the image:

```js
const maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50 MB
        let contentBuffer = [];
        let totalBytesInBuffer = 0;
        let contentType =  req.headers['content-type'] || 'application/octet';
        let fileName = req.headers['file-name'];

        req.on('data', chunk => {
          contentBuffer.push(chunk);
          totalBytesInBuffer += chunk.length;
        });

        req.on('end', async function() {
          contentBuffer = Buffer.concat(contentBuffer, totalBytesInBuffer);
            const context = {
                id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10),
                file_name: fileName,
                content_type: contentType,
                content_buffer: contentBuffer
            };
            const fileId = await image.create(context);

            res.status(201).json({succes: true});
    }
```

And when I GET  the image, this is the code:

```js
const context = {
            id: parseInt(req.params.id, 10)
        }

        const rows = await image.find(context);
        if (rows.length === 1) {
          res.status(200);

          res.set({
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': rows[0].content_type,
            'Content-Length': rows[0].file_length,
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + rows[0].file_name
          });

          res.send(rows[0].image);
}
```

image.create() and image.find() are just simple SQLs.
I do not know what to do, and how to get the corect file/image.

This is the tutorial link from where I tried to make this: 
https://jsao.io/2019/06/uploading-and-downloading-files-buffering-in-node-js/?unapproved=584&moderation-hash=a30eac5abf07cab32aeb6dd25cee2a1f#comment-584

Edit:
Here is my image.create:

```js
const createSql = `insert into test_image (
    id,
    file_name,
    content_type,
    image
  ) values (
    :id,
    :file_name,
    :content_type,
    :content_buffer
  )`;

async function create(context) {
    try {

        const binds = context;
        result = await database.simpleExecute(createSql, binds);
        return ;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Berlioz10, what tool are you using to test the GET?

Comment: @DanMcGhan, I am using Postman

Comment: Have you seen this? https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3407886/RWgp1fB5?version=latest

Comment: @DanMcGhan I tried to use it but I do not know what should I do with it

Comment: This says, "For binary response types, you should select “Send and download” which will let you save the response to your hard disk." https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/responses/

Comment: @DanMcGhan I used it, but let me be more specific:
My problem is that when I put the image in my database, it does not have a good format, because when I look at the notepad of the image, it gives me the header which i put it already, and a footer with random numbers. I do not know how to put the image in database without these things. Also I just realized that you are the guy who made the tutorial :).

Comment: And also, if you would like to help me privately ( just if you want) here is my discord tag: beans#2889

Comment: You can't open an image in the database with Notepad. To verify the content of the image in the database, you should open the record with a tool like SQL Developer and use the preview feature for the given column. Try that and let us know what you see.

Comment: See this for details: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Comment: @DanMcGhan This is what it happens when I put the image directly into database, which is fine:
https://imgur.com/a/xP8vvQR
And this is what it happens when I put the image with my POST request, which is not fine:
https://imgur.com/a/ny9gjDr
And also, when I download the image from database or with a GET request, some text of the image should not be there:
https://imgur.com/a/5o0npd2
Now I think that my problem is more clear.

Comment: Don't worry about the GET until you verify the POST is working using SQL Developer. Please add the code for `image.create` to your question.

Comment: Also, have you tried downloading and testing the demo app? There's a link at the top of the post that says "Get the code here".

Comment: @DanMcGhan I edited my question just now, and now I will install the demo app and use it.

Comment: `image.create` looks okay. Let me know how the test with the demo app goes. Once we know something works we can try to figure out why your code isn't working.

Comment: I tried the demo, but it didnt work.. I have the same problem

Comment: And I think I found the cause of this problem. When I do ```req.on('data')``` i'm taking all the data, not only the form data. But still I do not know how to take only the form-data

Comment: @DanMcGhan i forgot to tag you

Comment: The `req.on('data')` issue doesn't explain the fact that the demo app didn't work. I think it may be helpful if we were to meet online. If you're interested, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or use this contact form (https://jsao.io/contact/).